# ¿Error al pasar variable de Javascript a PHP desde el mismo archivo?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Antes que nada mencionar que encontré preguntas similares a esta con posibles soluciones o cerradas por estar duplicadas pero sin una solución.

Para pasar la variable de `JavaScript` a `php` decidi hacerlo con `Ajax` de esta manera:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ejecutar(){
  console.log("Inicia");
  var count = 5;
  $.ajax({
   url: "index.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {num:count},

   success : function(json) {
          console.log("success");
      },

      error : function(xhr, status) {
          console.log("error "+" xhr: "+xhr+" Status: "+status);
      },

      complete : function(xhr, status) {
          console.log("complete "+" xhr: "+xhr+" Status: "+status);
          console.log("count = "+count);
          console.log("num = "+num);
      }
  });
  console.log("Fin");
            }
 </script>
```

Y así quiero obtener el valor de la variable en `php`:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['num'])){
 echo "num = ".$identificador;
}else{
 echo "variable vacia";
}
?>
```

Este es mi archivo `index.php` completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax con php</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ejecutar(){
            console.log("Inicia");
            var count = 5;
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {num:count},
                success : function(json) {
                    console.log("success");
                },

                error : function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("error "+" xhr: "+xhr+" Status: "+status);
                },

                complete : function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("complete "+" xhr: "+xhr+" Status: "+status);
                    console.log("count = "+count);
                    console.log("num = "+num);
                }
            });
            console.log("Fin");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        echo "num = ".$identificador;
    }else{
        echo "variable vacia";
    }
?>
    <button type="button" onclick="ejecutar();">Ejecutar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado que obtengo en la consola Developer Tools de Google Chrome es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y en el navegador lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo mencionar que es 1ra vez que hago esto así que si estoy omitiendo algo básico o simple una disculpa

Comment: Está claro que la variable `num` no está definida en el contexto adecuado para poder acceder dentro  del `complete` , declare la variable antes de `ajax`.

Comment: Es cierto pero si la declaro antes de `ajax` sin valor me la sigue marcando indefinida ejemplo: `var num;` y si le asigno un valor por ejemplo: `var num = 0;` lo deja igual y no toma el valor de `count` que es el que quiero llevar a `php`

Comment: Es que tiene más errores por ejemplo de donde sale la variable `$identificador` ?  , ¿No toma el valor de `count`? ¿está seguro? , imprima el valor de `json ` en el `success` y verá que retorna correcto lo de `PHP` _claro está que antes deberá cambiar la variable $identificador que no está definida por ningún lado_ en su lugar sería `echo "num = ".$_POST['num'];`

Comment: Si una disculpa se me paso al momento de copiar el código lo de `php` pero lo tenia asi: `$identificador = $_POST['num']; echo "num = ".$identificador;` de igual manera ya lo deje asi: `echo "num = ".$_POST['num'];` pero de igual forma veo que entra al `else` porque imprime variable vacia en el navegador y si imprimo el valor del `json` en el `success` me imprime toda la pagina con sus etiquetas `html` y veo que si llega el valor del `count` al `php` pero en la consola, sin embargo lo que no entiendo es porque en el navegador no me imprime correctamente el `echo "num = ".$_POST['num'];`

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta con un cuarto punto para el caso que menciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se aprecian errores puntuales a primera vista como :

- Tratar de imprimir variables sin ser declaradas ni asignadas con ningún valor *(PHP)* específicamente la variable `$identificador` para lo cuál mostrará un error de variable indefinida.
- No entiendo con que fin intenta imprimir la variable `num` ya que la está usando como la `clave` del valor  de la variable `count` a la cual accede desde `PHP`.
- El error que muestra en consola es justamente por esto , no está declarada a nivel de función para poder acceder,  solo será accesible para `ajax`. Por lo cuál la primera solución sería  declararla antes e inicializarla pero no tendría sentido ya que no usa para nada excepto para clave del valor enviado.
- Como está realizando la llamada `ajax` a mismo archivo `PHP` retornará el contenido `HTML` también , de preferencia crear otro archivo para solo el procesamiento de datos desde `PHP` y cambiaría en la `url` en `ajax` por ejemplo `test.php` donde iría solo su código `PHP` o cortar con `exit` *terminar la ejecución* y colocar el código al inicio del `html` , **Recomiendo la primera opción , crear un nuevo archivo**

Su código quedaría:

```
 <?php
  /* Para validar que la solicitud sea de tipo POST , (solo para ajax se ejecutará)*/
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        echo "num = ".$_POST['num'];
        exit(); /* Para que no siga imprimiendo el resto*/
    } else{
        echo "variable vacia";
        exit();
      }
   }
  ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Ajax con php</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ejecutar(){
            console.log("Inicia");
            var count = 5;
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {num:count},
                success : function(json) {
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(json);
                },


            });

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" onclick="ejecutar();">Ejecutar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El primer punto tienes toda la razón fue mi error al momento de copiar el código, en el 2do punto intentaba imprimir la variable num porque pensé que al entrar el `success` dicha variable se le asignaba el valor de `count` y de esa forma me quería asegurar que si se estaba llevando el valor de `count` al `php`, el 3er punto según yo estaba debuggeando pero ya entendí que no tiene sentido lo que hacia, bueno pero a todo esto en consola si veo que llega el valor del `count`(5) al `php` pero en el navegador me sigue imprimiendo variable vacía

Comment: Verificar la actualización de mi respuesta. Espero ayude , saludos.

Comment: Veo que si funciona pero me surgen 2 dudas que se desvian un poco de la pregunta inicial, la 1ra: ¿Porque no veo en el navegador lo que imprimo con el `echo` en el `if` del `php`? y la 2da: ¿Porque si se ve en la consola de Chrome? según estuve leyendo para imprimir una variable de php en la consola es necesario instalar algunos plugins de debuggeo o algo por el estilo

Comment: creo es porque imprimo el `json` vdd

Comment: La respuesta es obvia, no se visualiza porque en ningún momento añade los valores al `document`  y se muestran en consola porque añade el `console.log()` nada más , para  poder visualizar el resultado podría crear un `div` con un `id`resultado y dentro del `success` tendría algo así `$('#resultado').append(json);` donde añade al `div` el valor retornado por `PHP`

Comment: Si ahora comprendo muchas gracias, creo que me pondré a estudiar y practicar mas porque según yo ya sabia lo básico pero veo que aun me falta, saludos!

Comment: Oye @Dev. Joel disculpa pero no entiendo como retornarle el valor al `json` y visualizarlo con `$('#resultado').append(json);` es decir en `php` debo hacerlo con la clausula `return`?

Comment: Buen día @Dev. Joel ya entendí como imprimir el `echo` desde el `success` añadiendo el valor al `document` pero no entiendo porque si uso el valor que envió desde el `Ajax` al `php` como variable en el `where` de una consulta `MySQL` lo detecta como si no le pasara nada a la variable, pero si hago un `alert(json);` o un `console.log(json);` en el `success` del `Ajax` de mi consulta `SQL` se ve que si esta el valor en el `where`, crees que debería hacer una nueva pregunta o me podrías aclarar mi duda desde aquí?

Comment: @ElCóndor una nueva pregunta, los comentarios no se pueden utilizar para conversaciones extendidas. Saludos.

Comment: ya hice la pregunta por si tienes oportunidad de checarla https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87127/consulta-mysql-en-php-no-reconoce-variable-enviada-desde-javascriptajax saludos