# Consulta MySQL en php no reconoce variable enviada desde ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Para pasar la variable de `JavaScript` a `php` lo hago con `Ajax` de esta manera:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function ejecutar(num_js){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mi_php.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {num:num_js},
               success : function(json){
               $('#contenedor-texto').html(json);
                       console.log("success");
                       console.log(json);
                       alert(json);
                       }
              });
          }
 </script>
```

Y así obtengo el valor de la variable en `php`:

```
<?php
     $num = $_POST["num"];
?>
```

Este es mi archivo `index.php` completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax con php</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ejecutar(num_js){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mi_php.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {num:num_js},
               success : function(json){
               $('#contenedor-texto').html(json);
                       console.log("success");
                       console.log(json);
                       alert(json);
                       }
              });
          }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="ejecutar('12');">Ejecutar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi archivo `mi_php.php` completo:

```
   <?php
        $num = $_POST["num"];
        echo "Num = ".$num." ";

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'passw');
        if (!$link){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * from tabla where num = '".$num."' ";
        echo "Consulta SQL = ".$sql;
        $result_q = mysql_query($sql);
        $array_return = array();
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_q)){
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo1'] = $result['campo1'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo2'] = $result['campo2'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo3'] = $result['campo3'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo4'] = $result['campo4'];
        }
?>
```

El `console.log(json);` y el `alert(json);` del archivo `index.php` me muestran lo siguiente:

```
Num = 12 Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = '12'
```

Pero el `echo "Consulta SQL = ".$sql;` de la linea 10 del archivo `mi_php.php` me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = ''
```

Y el resultado de la consulta `SQL` en la página web es como si hubiera hecho esto:

```
SELECT * from tabla where num = ''
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `num_js`? ¿Y cómo se lo mandas a tu función `ejecutar()`?

Comment: La función `ejecutar` espera un parámetro pero en el botón no se le envía nada.

Comment: Tienen razón me disculpo por haber copiado mal el código si tengo un parámetro de hecho para el ejemplo seria un 12 la función la repito varias veces y le asigno el valor manualmente, en un momento corrijo el código

Comment: @ElCóndor no se ve un posible error en su código, además no se entiende bien en `console.log(json)`  muestra _(Num = 12 Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = '12')_ es porque está llegando correctamente el valor. ¿Cuál es su pregunta?

Comment: Exacto si el valor si llega porque el resultado de la consulta `MySQL` es como si la variable `$num` estuviera vacía o porque el `console.log(json);` muestra `(Num = 12 Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = '12')` pero el `echo "Consulta SQL = ".$sql;` muestra: `(SELECT * from tabla where num = '')` acaso no puedo utilizar el valor enviado por `ajax` en la consulta `MySQL` de `php`?

Comment: @ElCóndor , la variable está llegando correctamente al PHP y se está usando, por eso recibes `Num = 12 Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = '12'` en la consola javascript, pero si accedes al PHP de manera directa desde el navegador entonces no estás enviando el valor requerido, por eso te muestra la salida `SELECT * from tabla where num = ''`. Ahora, la pregunta es, ¿qué quieres hacer con los datos recibidos desde la base de datos? No estás haciendo nada con ellos, ¿esperas enviarlos como resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que cambies tu función Ajax para que pueda recibir una respuesta de tipo JSON

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function ejecutar(num_js){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mi_php.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {num:num_js},
               success : function(json){
               $('#contenedor-texto').html(json);
                       console.log("success");
                       console.log(json);
                       alert(json);
                       }
              });
          }
 </script>
```

Y luego mandes a la consola el resultado para ver que te devuelve

```
   <?php
        $num = $_POST["num"];

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'passw');
        if (!$link){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * from tabla where num = '".$num."' ";
        $result_q = mysql_query($sql);
        $array_return = array();
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_q)){
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo1'] = $result['campo1'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo2'] = $result['campo2'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo3'] = $result['campo3'];
            $array_return[$result['campo']]['campo4'] = $result['campo4'];
        }

      echo json_encode(array('num' => $num, 'sql' => $sql,'data' => $array_return));
?>
```

Agregue para que retorne el valor de la variable **$sql**, pero nunca debes enviar tus queries en tus respuesta. Esto es solo para un ambiente de desarrollo.

Comment: Hola @Javier oye pero en el `alert(json);` que hago en el `success` del `ajax` puedo ver que el `$sql` retorna completo (con el valor de la variable que pase de `ajax` a `php`) o nose si te entendí mal, bueno de todos modos modifique el código y ahora ejecuta el `$sql` sin que yo de clic y veo que sigue ejecutando el `$sql` con la variable vacía, nose si tenga algo que ver el tipo de conexión que hago es decir que ya esta obsoleta :/

Comment: en la primera linea del archivo php, escribe esto print_r($_POST); die(0);   y comparte los resultados

Comment: me muestra lo siguiente: `Array ( )`

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no esta llegando nada desde tu función ajax. Elimina las dos lineas que colocaste por mi solicitud. Con motivos de prueba, cambia el $_POST por $_GET y abre el enlace directamente desde tu navegador de internet de esta forma mi_php.php?num=2 y confirmas si visualizas resultados.

Comment: nadamas duda puse `print_r($_POST["num"]); die(0);` y no me imprime nada

Comment: Ya hiciste esto --> Eso quiere decir que no esta llegando nada desde tu función ajax. Elimina las dos lineas que colocaste por mi solicitud. Con motivos de prueba, cambia el $_POST por $_GET y abre el enlace directamente desde tu navegador de internet de esta forma mi_php.php?num=2 y confirmas si visualizas resultados.

Comment: disculpa no había leído tu respuesta si ya lo hice y veo que de esa forma si llega el valor de `num` a la consulta `sql`

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta indicar el `dataType:'json'` en tu Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function ejecutar(num_js){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mi_php.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {num:num_js},
            dataType:'json',
               success : function(json){
               $('#contenedor-texto').html(json);
                       console.log("success");
                       console.log(json);
                       alert(json);
                       }
              });
          }
 </script>
```

Segun la fuente de JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Alterno a esto puedes probar mandándolo en la URL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function ejecutar(num_js){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mi_php.php?num='+num_js,
            type:'POST',
            data: {},
               success : function(json){
               $('#contenedor-texto').html(json);
                       console.log("success");
                       console.log(json);
                       alert(json);
                       }
              });
          }
 </script>
```

Comment: Ya se lo agregue y cuando se lo agrego no me ejecuta ni el `alert(json);` ni el `console.log(json);` del `success`

Comment: Si lo copiaste tal cual lo puse se me fue la coma al final del dataType

Comment: Si vi lo de la coma y se la agregue además agregue `error : function(error){console.log(error);}` y en la consola me muestra lo siguiente: Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort
:
function (a)
always
:
function ()
complete
:
function ()
done
:
function ()
error
:
function ()
fail
:
function ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
function ()
getResponseHeader
:
function (a)
isRejected
:
function ()
isResolved
:
function ()
overrideMimeType
:
function (a)
pipe

Comment: :
function (a,c)
promise
:
function (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
"Num = 12 Consulta SQL = SELECT * from tabla where num = '12'"
setRequestHeader
:
function (a,b)
status
:
200
statusCode
:
function (a)
statusText
:
"parsererror"
success
:
function ()
then
:
function (a,c)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta el error que me comentas lo desconozco, lo que te comento de mi respuesta lo saque de la documentación de Jquery